# Rails - how to sort the results of a cascading collection select form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've gotten my cascading collection_select form working like I want, but now I want to figure out how I can sort the updated results of the children fields alphabetically.

My custom actions in my controller:

```
def update_areas
   city_id =  (params[:city_id].nil? || params[:city_id].empty?) ? 0 : params[:city_id].to_i
   # updates artists and songs based on genre selected
   if city_id == 0
     @areas = []
     @neighborhoods = []

    else
      city = City.find(params[:city_id])
      # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
      @areas = city.areas.map{|a| [a.name, a.id]}
      @neighborhoods = Neighborhood.where(:area_id => city.areas.each{|a| a.id}).map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}
  end
  @areas.insert(0, "Select an Area")
  @neighborhoods.insert(0, "Select a neighborhood") 
end

def update_neighborhoods
    # updates songs based on artist selected
    area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
    @neighborhoods = area.neighborhoods.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a neighborhood")
end
```

Form code:

```
<div id="city">
    <p>City:</p>
    <%= f.collection_select(:city_id,  City.order('name ASC'),  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a City"}, {:id => 'cities_select'}) %>
    <br />
</div>

<div id="area">
    <p>City area:</p>
    <%= f.collection_select(:area_id, [], :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select an Area"}, {:id => 'areas_select'}) %>
    <br />
</div>

<div id="neighborhood">
    <p>Neighborhood:</p>
    <%= f.collection_select(:neighborhood_id, [], :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Neighborhood"}, {:id => 'neighborhoods_select'}) %>
    <br />
</div>
```

I know I can do something like Area.order('name ASC') in the form code, but I want to leave it blank until the city has been selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the order doing this:

```
@areas = city.areas.order("name asc").map{|a| [a.name, a.id]}
@neighborhoods = Neighborhood.where(:area_id => city.areas.each{|a| a.id}).order("name asc").map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}
```

And in the update code:

```
@neighborhoods = area.neighborhoods.sort_by(&:name).map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a neighborhood")
```